# Theming Mail.app to look like iPad's Mail.app or Thunderbird

Tags: macos, ipad, snow-leopard, mac, mail.app

Is there a way to theme Mail.app in Snow Leopard to look like iPads Mail application?

Maybe with a Thunderbird skin or something else?

Comment: Do you want to make Thunderbird look like the iPad's mail app, or the Mac's Mail.app look like the iPad?

Comment: For a more "iPad-like" interface, check Sparrow: http://www.sparrowmailapp.com/

Comment: is there a thunderbird skin?

Comment: If you can hold out a couple of months, [Mac OS X 10.7 “Lion”](http://www.apple.com/macosx/lion/) will have an iPad-like version of Mail.app when it ships this summer.

Answer (score 1):

The Mail.app program in Snow Leopard is not easily themable.

There are 3rd party applications that can change various theme elements (eg http://mac.appstorm.net/how-to/graphics-how-to/an-introduction-to-changing-os-x-themes/) but it is unlikely that even these will get the exact look you are after.

And most of them will change the entire look and feel of the operating system, not just selected applications.